# Use rich text editor in 'Edit Media', for attachment media description

Tags: media, attachments, visual-editor

I have the following in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', function( $settings ){
  if( get_post_type() == 'attachment'){
    $settings = [
      'wpautop'       => true,
      'textarea_name' => 'content',
      'textarea_rows' => 10,
      'media_buttons' => false,
      'tinymce' => true,
    ];
    return $settings;
 }
});
```

And this does add the visual tab when I go to edit media in the Wordpress admin. However, once I save my changes, and then go back to edit media and save again, it converts all the html to encoded html entities.

For example,

```
<h2>Another H2</h2>
```

becomes

```
&lt;h2&gt;Another H2&lt;/h2&gt;
```

Which prints the html on the front end. So I must be missing some essential piece that preserves html. What to I need to add to be able to use the visual tab when editing media descriptions?

[This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255451/add-visual-editor-to-media-edit-screen#answer-255661) is almost a correct answer but it doesn't account for this HTML issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I must be missing some essential piece that preserves html.

No, your code is OK.

However, I would require the second parameter ([`$editor_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_editor_settings/#parameters)) and check whether its value is `attachment_content` which is the editor ID for the media description textarea on the "Edit Media" page. I also wouldn't add the `'textarea_name' => 'content'` part.

> once I save my changes, and then go back to edit media and save again,
> it converts all the html to encoded html entities

Yes, and it happens because WordPress applies [`format_to_edit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/format_to_edit/) ([see source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L3276)) and then [`format_for_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/format_for_editor/) ([see source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L272)), and these functions both use `htmlspecialchars()`, therefore the HTML would be escaped *twice*.

So for example, `<h2>` becomes `&amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;` which in the Text/HTML mode of the editor becomes `&lt;h2&gt;` and then in the Visual mode appears as `<h2>`.

### So how to fix the issue?

Unfortunately, as of WordPress 5.8, there is no hook for bypassing/disabling the first or second HTML escaping, but you can try the following trick which disables the second escaping by unhooking `format_for_editor()` from the [`the_editor_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_editor_content/) **if** the current editor ID is `attachment_content`:

```php
function my_fix_the_editor_content_double_escaping( $content ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'format_for_editor' );

    // * We're not actually modifying the content, but only adding the above code.
    return $content;
}

// * Use this instead of the code you have in the question.
add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', function ( $settings, $editor_id ) {
    // Check if the current page is the "Edit Media" page (at wp-admin/post.php), and if
    // so, we customize the editor settings.
    if ( is_admin() && 'attachment' === get_current_screen()->id &&
        'attachment_content' === $editor_id
    ) {
        // Change only what need to be changed.
        $settings['wpautop']       = true;
        $settings['textarea_rows'] = 10;
        $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
        $settings['tinymce']       = true;

        add_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'my_fix_the_editor_content_double_escaping', 1 );
    }

    return $settings; // Note: ALWAYS return it!
}, 10, 2 );
```

So I hope that helps and don't worry, WordPress will automatically re-hook `format_for_editor()` back onto `the_editor_content`, therefore no need to manually re-hook it.

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer that worked perfectly. Thank you.